# Maintain Table History with Nhibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, iinterceptor

I have a situation where I have to maintain History of a table.

For Eg: I have PaymentTransaction Table and I want to keep PaymentTransactionHistory for auditing purposes.

Do we have anything in NHIbernate that can be used to achieve this. I read about IInterceptor and Events and couldn't really understand if they could be of any use in my case.

I am using Fluent NHIbernate.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[NHibernate Envers](http://envers.bitbucket.org/) may also be an option for you - but possibly an overkill for the usage you mentioned.

Comment: Yes you are right and is the reason why I am trying to avoid using it. I have made it to wotk by using Nhibernate Events. Thanks for your input though.

Answer (score 0):

In my project this is done by an interceptor, using following methods:

- When something got deleted, process it in OnDelete
- When something inserted into DB, process it in OnSave
- When something changes, process it in OnFlushDirty
- There are some other methods for handling collection.

Just try them, it's not difficult.